# How can I stop a SKAction.repeatActionForever action at a action boundary?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a sequence of SpriteKit actions that I create and then repeat forever on a node, but that I want to stop eventually. My sequence rotates a disk left, right, and left returning to the original rotation before starting again. However, when I remove the action, it stops without completing and so the original rotation is not restored.

I could save the original rotation state and restore it, but I want to know is there is a way to tell SpriteKit to only interrupt the action at the sequence boundary?

```
func wiggle() -> SKAction {
    let wiggleLeft = SKAction.rotateByAngle(+0.04, duration: 0.1)
    let wiggleRight = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-0.08, duration: 0.2)
    let wiggleBack = SKAction.rotateByAngle(+0.04, duration: 0.1)
    let wiggle = SKAction.sequence([wiggleLeft, wiggleRight, wiggleBack])
    let wiggleForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(wiggle)
    return wiggleForever
}

disk.runAction(wiggle(), withKey: "wiggle")
...
disk.removeActionForKey("wiggle")    // unfortunately stops mid-wiggle
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code after `disk.removeActionForKey("wiggle")`:
    `disk.runAction.rotateToAngle(/*desired final angle of rotation*/)`